# Is it possible for an address of an std::array member to be null in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it possible to modify `a` to make the if-statement fail?

```
std::array<int,4> a = {{1,2,3,4}};

for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
{
    auto ptr = &a[i];
    if (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        printf("value at %d is %d\n",i,a[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid array\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what prompted this question? What led you to believe that this might be possible?

Comment: There is nothing legal you can do to get a null in the middle of a contiguous block of memory like  an array. Can't think of anything illegal either, but Undefined Behaviour can be most surprising.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I ran into that code segment while trying to increase line coverage.

Comment: Remove the check. It's as misguided as artificially increasing line coverage. Eliminating the dead code will address both problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of an element in a standard library container can't be null, as long as you are using the container's API properly. This is because, assuming you meet all preconditions of the API, the container guarantees that all of its elements are valid objects, and a valid object never has a null address. As soon as you violate the preconditions, however (for example, popping from an empty vector), the entire program has undefined behaviour, and you might end up seeing "impossible" branches of `if` statements getting executed.

In the snippet shown, for example, attempting to access `a[4]` will give the program undefined behaviour. It probably will not result in the `else` branch being taken, but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

The `if (ptr != nullptr)` block is entirely redundant. It does nothing. The test can never fail. The `std::array<int, 4>` is created right there as a local automatic variable, it can not fail to have a valid address for all its elements.